# Unity MVP architecture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mvp

I'm trying to make an MVP architecture in a unity 2d project.
My idea is to separate presenter and model from the engine.
And so the question is how to make the player move correctly.

```
public class PlayerModel
{
    private Vector2 position;
    private float speed;
    public void UpdatePosition(Vector2 movement)
    {
        position += movement * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

My problem is that Vector2 and Time.deltaTime are pulled from UnityEngine.

Comment: why? Like why separate them from the engine entirely? But well if really necessary: Have a shared translation library between the Unity project and - whatever the other code is running in - and have your own custom Vector2 and forth and back convert between that and the Unity one